# Alignment issues with a WPF application and Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows

I just deployed my WPF application to Windows 8 and was shocked to see that none of my labels line up with their respective textboxes! In both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 they snap-to and line up perfectly in the design view. They also line up perfectly when the application runs in Windows 7 and XP. I'm using the same resolution/DPI settings for both deployments. Has anyone else noticed this issue? Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I have [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195851/wpfs-textblock-differences-between-windows-7-and-windows-8). Have you managed to find  the source of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Are you manipulating the size of the TextBoxes or labels in your application?

Comment: No, not in any way whatsoever. Default font sizes, default vertical alignment and vertical content alignment, etc.